# Android-Kotlin Control nullable strings from firebase push()

Tags: android, kotlin

During getting key value from my Firebase, I'm in trouble to deal with null type exception. What I've got is [Type mismatch. Required : String. Found : String?]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H2IEvOM7PrwX8ZUBmSjgEbp9c-mxVD4S

Kotlin : $kotlin_version
Firebase-database : 19.0.0

**I tried**
`tried 1 -> var postId? = ""
tried 2 -> post.postId = newRef.getKey()
tried 3 -> post.postId? = newRef.key`
But they not worked.

**WriteActivity.kt**

```
    class Post {
       var postId = ""
    // tried 1 -> var postId? = ""
    }

    val post = Post()
    val newRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").push()

    post.postId = newRef.key
    // tried 2 -> post.postId = newRef.getKey()
    // tried 3 -> post.postId? = newRef.key
```

What I want to achieve for this is get key and store it to the post.postId.

Your aid would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what you're trying to do here, but this should work for you:

```
class Post {
    var postId: String? = ""
}
```

Alternatively, if you want `postId` to never be null, you could keep what you have and write this:

```
post.postId = newRef.key!!
```